# Is Two Way Repeated Measures ANOVA appropriate?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I've conducted a study investigating if an intervention decreases the number of violations a restaurant receives during an inspection.

50 restaurants are inspected, 2 months later they're given an intervention, 2 months later they're inspected again.

The inspection consists of 30 potential violations they can receive. I.e., Restaurant "A" may receive 3 violations before the intervention and 2 violations after.

I've conducted a paired t-test and Wilcoxon signed-rank test and found that there was a significant reduction in violations on the post inspection.

I know want to do another test. There are two types of violations (high risk and low risk). I want to investigate if there's a mean difference in the violation types pre and post intervention.

Example table with fake data below

[image: Example table with fake data]

Each value in the above table is the average of n=50 restaurants.

Should I use a two-way repeated measures ANOVA?